# Final attribute of a final datatype?

Tags: java, static, final

What happens when I declare something like:

```
public static final String forma = "Rectangular";
```

Isn't it redundant? Being String a final class, what would it change not setting *`forma`* as final? For `static`, I think it is not making any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **String is a final class**,and  **final** keyword makes references final not object final.
Final object means it can't be altered but final reference means it can't be assigned to another object after first assignment.

Being final means you can not modify the object `String s="hello"`, `"hello"` is the string object and it cant be modified, but about `s` if its a non-final reference and i do thing like:`s=s.concat("bing")` then, `"hello"` is taken can concatenated with `"bing"` object and then assigned to `s` means `"hello" and "bing"` objects are not modified they lost their references and non-final reference `s` is now referring to a new object `"hellobing"`.

I surely wanna help you more if you find this interesting.

Comment: So for a `String s`, being its class a final one, what wouldn't be allowed talking about the references.

Answer (score 3):

`final` make sure reference is not assigned to new value.

If you don't make it `final`, it is valid to assign some other value to `forma` (or) you can do some operation on `Rectangular` and assign results back to `forma`

Answer (score 1):

For object-types 'final' modifier means that REFERENCE to this object cannot be changed, not it's value!

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it redundant?

**No, it is not redundant.** It is constant. Every keyword of this statement has meaning. `final` make it **immutable**, `static` make it **class variable** and `public` make it **globally accessible**.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword is heavily overloaded, and means very different things in different contexts:

- On fields and local variables, it indicates that the content of a reference cannot be changed.  (This is different from immutability.)
- On classes, it indicates that the class cannot be subclassed.
- On methods, it indicates that the method cannot be overridden in subclasses.